# wp_set_object_terms() taking long execution time

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv, cron

i'm working with custom WordPress importer that is importing posts and other metadata using large csv file(may be 40000 plus records in file). everything is fine but the `wp_set_object_terms()` taking long time during import process.
there may be multiple terms for single post like category,tags or custom taxonomy.

i'm using WordPress cron due large csv file and importing data after every 2 minute.
cron executes after every 2 minutes and process the records in chunks, like it will pick 0-200 records then 2nd time it will pick 200-400 records then 400-600 and so on.

but due to `wp_set_object_terms()` the process taking more then 2 minute and it increases after each cron.
like 1st 200 records take 90 second then 2nd 200 records will take 93 and it goes up and up after each cron.

```html
foreach($terms_to_set as $tax => $ids ){

 wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $ids, $tax, false );

 }
```

the hosting guys told that `wp_set_object_terms()` query is time consuming and really it is.
after disabling this the process goes super fast.

so please let me know your thoughts if have any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102361/26350) will help?

Comment: I am having the same issue, any solution did you get??